# How to get the coordinate range for a three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I create a scene with html and javascript, with a camera and and a renderer and display that scene in a browser: How can I find out the visible range of the scene?

In my concrete case I display just a 2 dimensional x/y scene with objects on it. But, given a scene, what are the minimum x/y values so that an object created e.g. with

```
var object = new THREE.Mesh( circle.clone(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: new THREE.Color('white'), opacity: 0.5 } ) );
object.position.x = ??;
object.position.y = ??;
object.position.z = 0;
object.geometry.scale(0.8, 0.8, 1);
scene.add( object );
```

is just visible at the edge of the browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply get the size of your 3D world (the visible part, depends on your camera settings), e.g. :

```
const vFOV = (camera.fov * Math.PI) / 180;
const height = 2 * Math.tan(vFOV / 2) * Math.abs(camera.position.z);
const width = height * camera.aspect;

object.position.x = -width / 2;
object.position.y = -height / 2;
```